# PHP7 MySQL Invalid default value for 'expiry_date' PDO Database Install

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, pdo

Recently installed php7.0-fpm + Nginx + MySQL on a Ubuntu 16 x64 box.

When getting a php installer to PDO to a database in order to add files it does the following:

```
There seems to be an error. Please try again.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'expiry_date' in /var/www//install/index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /var/www//install/index.php(31): 
PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www//install/index.php(152): try_query(Array) #2 {main}
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in /var/www//install/index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /var/www//install/index.php(31): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www//install/index.php(152): try_query(Array) #2 {main}
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in /var/www//install/index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /var/www//install/index.php(31): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www//install/index.php(152): try_query(Array) #2 {main}
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in /var/www//install/index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /var/www//install/index.php(31): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www//install/index.php(152): try_query(Array) #2 {main}
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' in /var/www//install/index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /var/www//install/index.php(31): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www//install/index.php(152): try_query(Array) #2 {main}
```

Have I missed something in setup? It was all working fine on a Ubuntu 14 php5 system.

Heres some of the table insertion to help assess:

```
'0' => array(
                'table' => TABLE_FILES,
                'query' => 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'.TABLE_FILES.'` (
                              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                              `url` text NOT NULL,
                              `filename` text NOT NULL,
                              `description` text NOT NULL,
                              `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                              `uploader` varchar('.MAX_USER_CHARS.') NOT NULL,
                              `expires` INT(1) NOT NULL default \'0\',
                              `expiry_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                              `public_allow` INT(1) NOT NULL default \'0\',
                              `public_token` varchar(32) NULL,
                              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                            ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
                            ',
                'params' => array(),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `expiry_date` column, the `not null` constraint without any default causes the default to be set as 0, which is not accepted as a default value in MySQL for timestamps.

Use a default timestamp for the `expiry_date` field.

You can check the discussion on the following thread regarding the issue.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3602